# Add nanosecond resolution unix time

Tags: powershell

I am currently converting a date time value to unix time so that it can be inserted into a time series database (influxdb) using the following code:

```
(Get-Date -Date $_.timecreated -UFormat %s)
```

Unfortunately influx requires nano second resolution while the above gives me ms resolution. What is the best way to add nano second resolution that influx can accept as a valid unix timestamp? I have tries adding some 0000 characters at the end but that does not always work.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to compute the unix timestamp yourself like this, by computing the offset from the unix epoch:

```
$utime = ((Get-Date -Date $_.timecreated) - (Get-Date "1/1/1970")).TotalSeconds
```

that gives you a double that you can format as you like. This will give nanosecond precision:

```
"{0:F06}" -f $utime
```

**Update:** It's important to note that I don't think `Get-Date` will give you a nanosecond precision of the time. On my machine the nanosecond place value is always 0.

Comment: Correct. Get-Date does not have nanosecond precision as i get zero values for it

Comment: @JohnB Do you actually require nanosecond resolution? I don't think you can get it.